# For loop different end conditions in the same line?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Suppose you want to loop `from i=0 to i=n and j=0 to j=m` and that `m!=n`. Is it possible to shorten the following two loops into one?

```
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){}
for(int j=0; j<=m; j++){}
```

To something along

```
for(int i=0,j=0; i<=n, j<=m; i++, j++){}
```

In essence I want the loop to say "increment both i and j by one, stop incrementing i if i=n but keep incrementing j if m>n" or the other way around if `n>m`.

May seem trivial or stupid but I am curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naively, we want to do something like:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i <= n || j <= m; i = Math.min(n, i+1), j = Math.min(m, j+1))
```

...but this won't terminate, because the maximum value for `i` is `n` and the maximum value for `j` is `m`, and one of those will always be true.

The problem is much simpler if you're willing to let (for `n < m`) `i` finish at `n+1`, as we could write:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i <= n || j <= m; i = Math.min(n+1, i+1), j = Math.min(m+1, j+1))
```

This is complicated only if you want to keep (for `n < m`) `i = n` while `j` finishes incrementing. The complexity is isolated to getting the loop to terminate at the right time, while still allowing `j` to finish incrementing.

To get the loop to terminate, we want to increment the *larger* number one step past its maximum, so that we hit the termination criteria. Since we know at least one of `i <= n` and `j <= m` will always be true, let's focus on making *both* always true, and change our termination criteria to

```
i <= n && j <= m
```

In the case where `n < m`, `i` will finish incrementing before `j`, and so we need to let `j` increment one past its effective maximum in order to violate `i <= n && j <= m`. A similar condition holds for `n > m`, but instead, we need to increment `i` one past `n`.

Notice, though, that if `n == m`, we can safely increment *both* one past their respective limits, and the termination criteria will hit at the same time. The loop below handles *any* positive input `n` or `m` and terminates correctly given your conditons, while allowing the lesser of `n` or `m` to become the maximum value for the respective iterator.

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0, nadj = n + (n >= m ? 1 : 0), madj = m + (m >= n ? 1 : 0) 
   i <= n && j <= m;
   i = Math.min(nadj, i+1), j = Math.min(madj, j+1))
```

Worth noting, we compute `nadj` and `madj` in the first section to avoid recomputing them during every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

```
for(int i=0,j=0; i+1<=n || j+1<=m; ){
    if(i<n) i++;
    if(j<m) j++;
    // do stuff here
    // keep in mind that i and j starts from 1
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nilgundag/4frCG/

Old Answer:

```
for(int i=0,j=0; i<=n || j<=m; ){
    if(i<=n) i++;
    if(j<=m) j++;
    // do stuff here
    // keep in mind that i and j starts from 1
}
```

Comment: I've just had another look at your answer too!  Have you tested it?  It seems to me that it would loop endlessly, because once i and j reach their final values of n and m, they never change again, but the loop condition is still true.  I am applying a downvote.

Comment: old answer is not looping endlessly, but it causes variable i to have a value n+1 if m is larger than n. I tested the code with a fiddle.

Comment: OK, I think that looks better.  I have replaced my downvote with an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one iterator i since you increment i and j by 1 every time.

```
for(int i=0; i<=n || i<=m;i++ ){
    if(i<=n) //{do first loop job}
    if(i<=m) //{do second loop job}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++:

```
for (int i=0, j=0; j<=m || i<=n; i+=i<=n, j+=j<=m ){}
```

JAVA:

```
for (int i=0, j=0; j<=m || i<=n; i+=(i<=n)?1:0, j+=(j<=m)?1:0 ){}
```