# How to write multiple FOR loop for displaying 2 variables?

Tags: jsp, for-loop

In my code i'm using two for loops. I want to display 2 array of values in dropdownlist. "wpvalue" is properly load. But "wpvalue1" load multiple times. How to change my code?

```
while (rs1.next()) {
    String wplist = rs1.getString("wplist");
    String wplistname = rs1.getString("wplistname");

    String wplist1[] = wplist.split("/");
    String wplist2[] = wplistname.split("/");
    String wpvalue = "";
    String wpvalue1 = "";

    for (int p = 0; p < wplist1.length; p++) {
        for (int q = 0; q < wplist2.length; q++) {
            wpvalue = wplist1[p];
            wpvalue1 = wplist2[q];  
        }
        buffer2 = buffer2 + "<option value='" + wpvalue + "'>" + wpvalue1 + "</option>";
    }
    buffer2 = buffer2 + "</select>";
    response.getWriter().println(buffer2);
}
```

Comment: If you indent your code correctly you will see the misplaced `buffer2 = buffer2 + "<option value`... (and `wpvalue = wplist1[p];` looks misplaced too)

Comment: i'm not clear can u re-edit my code?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938129/for-loop-different-end-conditions-in-the-same-line

Comment: Well, go through your code "manually", assume e.g. that `wplist` is `"A/B/C"` and `wplistname` is `"a/b/c"`, the interpret your code line by line, to see, how the values of `wpvalue` and `wpvalue1` change. (Btw. the variable names you use are horrible.)

Comment: Thanks dear #want2learn i  used ur suggestions. it's working fine